# Missing last word of string when I split the sentence into word

Tags: c++

I am missing the last word of string. this is code I used to store word into array.

```
string arr[10];
int Add_Count = 0;
string sentence = "I am unable to store last word"
string Words = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
    if (Sentence[i] == ' ')
    {
        arr[Add_Count] = Words;
        Words = "";
        Add_Count++;
    }
    else if (isalpha(Sentence[i]))
    {
        Words = Words + sentence[i];
    }
}
```

Let's print the arr:

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
{
  cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: what is `arr`? doesn't have a type

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff, it is a string. I missed to current that

Comment: Anyway, note that you only add a word to `arr` when you encounter a `' '` space. But there is no trailing space in `sentence`.

Comment: @NathanPierson, yes it is

Comment: yes, I see that @NathanPierson.

Comment: The short answer is strings don't end with `' '` or alpha-characters. The underlying `c_str()` ends with `'\0'`.

Comment: Also, if there are only 7 words in your sentence -- why would you try and print 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the word found when you see a blank character.

Since the end of the string is not a blank character, the insertion for the last word never happens.

What you can do is:

(1) If the current character is black, skip to the next character.

(2) See the next character of current character.

(2-1) If the next character is blank, insert the accumulated word.

(2-2) If the next character doesn't exist (end of the sentence), insert the accumulated word.

(2-3) If the next character is not blank, accumulate word.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you won't have to worry about punctuation, the easiest way to handle it is to throw the string into a `istringstream`. You can use the extraction operator overload to extract the "words". The extraction operator defaults to splitting on whitespace and automatically terminates at the end of the stream:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string sentence = // ... Get the string from cin, a file, or hard-code it here.
std::istringstream ss(sentence);

std::vector<std::string> arr;
arr.reserve(1 + std::count(std::cbegin(sentence), std::cend(sentence), ' '));
std::string word;
while(ss >> word) {
    arr.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` instead of `std::array` makes much more sense...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, it does. Dunno what I was thinking. Also added pre-allocation since the size is no longer constant and dependent on the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you lost the last word because when you go to the end the last word is not extracted yet. You can add this line to get the last word

```
if (Words.length() != 0) {
       arr[Add_Count] = Words;
       Words = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the very good approach by [@Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421178/casey), but adding the use of `std::vector` instead of an array, allows you to break a line into as many words as may be included in it. Using the `std::stringstream` and extracting with `>>` allows a simple way to tokenize the sentence while ignoring leading, multiple included and trailing whitespace.

For example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {
    
    std::string sentence = "  I    am    unable to        store last  word    ",
                word {};
    std::stringstream ss (sentence);        /* create stringstream from sentence */
    std::vector<std::string> words {};      /* vector of strings to hold words */
    
    while (ss >> word)                      /* read word */
        words.push_back(word);              /* add word to vector */
    
    /* output original sentence */
    std::cout << "sentence: \"" << sentence << "\"\n\n";
    
    for (const auto& w : words)     /* output all words in vector */
        std::cout << w << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tokenize_sentence_ss
sentence: "  I    am    unable to        store last  word    "

I
am
unable
to
store
last
word
```

If you need more fine-grained control, you can use `std::string::find_first_of` and `std::string::find_first_not_of` with a set of delimiters to work your way through a string finding the first character in a token with `std::string::find_first_of` and then skipping over delimiters to the start of the next token with `std::string::find_first_not_of`. That involves a bit more arithmetic, but is a more flexible alternative.

Comment: It's even easier for custom delimiters! Just use `std::getline(ss, word, delim)` and all text between the delimiters will be grabbed. The only drawback is it will not skip "empty" strings resulting from a delimiter immediately preceeding itself, e.g. `"Hello,,World"` with a comma delimiter will result in `"Hello", "", "World"`. But this is easily prevented with a boolean check for "skipping empty".

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the last word has no space after it, just add this line after `for` loop.

```
arr[Add_Count] = Words;
```

Answer (score 0):

***My version :***

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::istringstream iss("I am unable to store last word");
  std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), {});
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

***[Sample Run :](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1i1o8XhYOTUUfCSV)***

```
I
am
unable
to
store
last
word
```

Comment: Wow. Three expressions. Learn the algorithms header, people!...Now I want to test your version against mine. :)